# Span of set of vectors that are consisted of individual vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

I am given a set of vectors $u, v, w$ such that $span\{u, v, w\} = {\rm I\!R}^3 $.

I am then told to find if $S2$ and $S3$ span ${\rm I\!R}^3 $, where $S2 = \{u - v, v - w, w - u\}$ and $S3 = \{u, u + v, u + v + w\}$.

Under normal circumstances when actual vectors are provided, I would run the vectors through Gauss-Jordan Elimination to check if the systems have any zero rows to know if they span ${\rm I\!R}^n $. But in this case, I'm not provided with any concrete vectors, so I am assuming I need to check if the vectors can be expressed in terms of each other, i.e. whether there are 3 linearly independent vectors in each set.

Is there an efficient way to go about this, especially the part of checking if I can express the vectors in term of each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$u\in S_3\subset\mathrm{span}(S_3,S_2)$$ $$\frac12(u+v)-\frac12(u-v)=v\in\mathrm{span}(S_3,S_2)$$ as $u-v\in S_2,u+v\in S_3$ and $$(w+u+v)-(u+v)=w\in\mathrm{span}(S_3,S_2)$$ as $(w+u+v),(u+v)\in S_3$. Thus $\{u,v,w\}\subset\mathrm{span}(S_3,S_2)$ and hence $\mathrm{span}\{u,v,w\}\subseteq\mathrm{span}(S_3,S_2)$.

Comment: +1 nice : Question: does your answer have a typo :re "...as $(w + u + v), u \in S_3$..." -- should that be "...as $w, u \in S_3$..."

Comment: $w\not\in S_3$ but $w+u+v$ is

Comment: boy is this my day for blindness; that's the 2nd time today.  thanks for response.